# MySQL query syntax error with inner join

Tags: mariadb

I have the following query:

```
(
 SELECT * FROM salon_promo tt 
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT salon_id, MAX(promo_id) AS MaxDateTime 
       FROM salon_promo 
       GROUP BY salon_id) 
     groupedtt ON tt.salon_id = groupedtt.salon_id 
       AND tt.promo_id = groupedtt.MaxDateTime) 
   INNER JOIN salons USING (salon_id)
```

And recive the following error message :

> error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN salons USING (salon_id)' at line 1

When I use the following query:

```
SELECT * from salon_promo INNER JOIN salons USING (salon_id)
```

Everything works fine. And query from the ():

```
(
 SELECT * FROM salon_promo tt 
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT salon_id, MAX(promo_id) AS MaxDateTime 
       FROM salon_promo 
       GROUP BY salon_id) 
     groupedtt ON tt.salon_id = groupedtt.salon_id 
       AND tt.promo_id = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
)
```

Works fine too. What can cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your query is wrong**

This

```
groupedtt.MaxDateTime) 
                     ^^ )should remove
```

should be

```
groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

So final query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM salon_promo tt 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT salon_id, MAX(promo_id) AS MaxDateTime 
    FROM salon_promo 
    GROUP BY salon_id) 
groupedtt ON tt.salon_id = groupedtt.salon_id 
AND tt.promo_id = groupedtt.MaxDateTime 
INNER JOIN salons USING (salon_id)
```

Comment: error : Column 'salon_id' in from clause is ambiguous

Comment: `MaxDateTime` is a field's name. (`... MAX(promo_id) AS MaxDateTime ...`)

Comment: @Abdulla - yep, that's it! But instead of USING( salon_id ) we must place ON tt.salon_id = salons.salon_id ( using doesnt' work )

Comment: @NikitaPronchik happy to help :)